# Return internal value in Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to compile a contract and get a value from the contract by call.
I used https://remix.ethereum.org/

Code available in [gist](https://gist.github.com/pavoltravnik/a6400a2964e6ed3068f7e695699d0035).

The issue is, that after compilation with the latest version of Solidity compiler 0.6.1. it doesn't return decoded output. It works fine in version 5.1.6.

Contract on the top is built by 0.6.1.
Below is built by 5.1.6.

Calls behave like transacts.

Any mention in breaking changes and docs.

[image: remix calls]

Comment: Your contract is working fine. i think its a remix issue. If you look into the debugger log you will find that your contract is returning expected values.

Comment: Actually it doesn't return any value in "decoded output".

Comment: It was bug of remix, the issue is closed. https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/1424